# data updation is not reflected on the database in VB 2008

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I am using the following code for inserting data to the database

```
            bdcon.Open()
            Dim querystring As String
            Dim mycommand55 As New SqlCommand
querystring = "insert into Tr_Cashbook values(" + TextBox1.Text + "," + ComboBox1.Text + ",'" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + ComboBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + ComboBox3.Text + "'," & 0 & ",'" + DateTimePicker2.Value + "','" + ComboBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "')" 
                 Try mycommand55.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
                Binding()
```

this inserted data to database when programs is running but if i close the program and start again previous data i have inserted are lost ....why ?plz reply

Comment: @Oleg seems to be going in a good direction with the open Transaction.  Is there some other code in your situation that's not included in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious vulnerability to SQL injection attacks by not using parameterized queries or validating/cleansing the data before using it, it looks like you're not using the `querystring` variable anywhere.  You create it and then assign it a value, but you never tell the `SqlCommand` object to use it in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have opened transaction using class TransactionScope, which is not commits in proper way

**You should review and redesign** your approach when dealing with sql server, because your way is very vulnerable to sql injections. Try to rewrite the query using parameters, nor raw in-string values